# opposite to top

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm working with sql server 2005.

I have a view which sorts its columns according to order date. I call:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [OrderDate] 
FROM   [ordersview]
```

to get the latest time. How do I get the earliest time?

Comment: A view is a set of rows and does not have any default `ORDER`. You need to specify any required `ORDER BY` when selecting from the View if you require this. (NB: SQL Server 2000 did allow Ordered Views as [discussed here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx))

Comment: Strange. I'm using the Designer in 2008 Management Studio on my 2005 DB to create the view and it lets me specify ordering on columns. Why is that?

Comment: It only allows `ORDER BY` if the view definition also includes `TOP`. Then the `ORDER BY` refers to the `TOP` specification not the presentation order. In SQL Server 2000 it did conflate the two but this was not correct semantics and is no longer the case without enabling a specific backward compatibility trace flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 OrderDate FROM ordersview ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Also:

```
SELECT MIN(OrderDate) FROM ordersview
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a descending ordering:

```
select top 1 OrderDate from ordersview order by OrderDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, 
this is little bit tricky question.

Every body will say for white is opposite black.
And for first is it last.

but when u are not specifying initial order
what is really the first.

I think it is internal/vendor specific thing.

So both answers are right ,but actually not answering really  your question.

I'm not really mssql-guy but think that your select will return random
row (maybe depending on inserting sequence , or same internal db thing like rowId).

And what is opposite for random ?

One more thing is that, ordering is pretty demanding(resource/performance) function , 
for such thing u should have index on column.

And basically when u are doing select like that u should thing about real paging 
not only one item .

But then the result will have different order then original one ( so ... )

Comment: To quote: "view which sorts its columns according to orderdate". So he will be getting the lowest date with his sql.